# GUI programming to display record from disk in linux

Tags: python, linux, qt, user-interface, gtk

**What I Need to achieve**
I have a huge set (around 1 million) of records (each records of 500 bytes) on disk (a specific file) with below format

```
===========================================================
|X|a,b,c|O|m,n,g|X|t,a,c|X|e,p,q|O|u,q,p|X|r,t,s|O|l,m,a|
===========================================================
```

The first field consist of flag ('X') represents valid filled data, flag ('O') consists of structured data. For example, first set contains a valid data with a,b,c as its data (assume of a structure).

I need to display them on screen (linux) more like the `top` command output (in terms of simple - meaning keyboard input driven, dynamic GUI - like refresh, page-down options etc)  like -

```
Display Record From No XXX                    

Records Number                                Field 1                         Field 2                           Field 3
1                                                a                                b                                c
2                                                NA                               NA                               NA
3                                                t                                a                                c
4                                                o                                p                                q
5                                                NA                               NA                               NA
6                                                r                                t                                s
7                                                NA                               NA                               NA

F5 [Referesh]                Page-Down [Next Page]                Page-Up [Prev Page]                Ctrl+C [Exit]
```

Where the value XXX, would be entered by user and one page of records are shown.

**Questions**

a. Since the display is similar to that of top/ atop command, Can you please let me know the base on which such commands are displaying the output?

b. Any specific language (like GTK,QT etc) which are more suitable for such operations? Basically any better language apart from the one used in top/atop command. (May be this question is subjective) but would like to collect best opinion?

c. Now, if I want to template the structure (by providing in config file) so that different kinds of structures can be read and displayed, From which language is this best possible? Note : Here I mean, file 1 contains structure A data only. file 2 contains structure B data. So while reading file 2, I would like to load the structure configuration of Structure B and run the tool for display.

PS :
The above files are in-fact written to file with a normal C application (hinting the structure and its fields would be of C basic data type attributes).

Comment: For top-like GUI functionality, use the [curses](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) library.

Comment: curses is an excellent package, make sure to try out ncurses though from GNU. (new curses ;))

Comment: GTK+ and Qt are not "languages", they're user interface toolkit libraries. At least GTK+ can be used from a great number of different programming languages (through "bindings").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a. There are many implementations of `top`. Some of them use `curses\ncurses` libraries.

b. If there is no reason to make your program operating from the console (text mode), then of course graphics mode, on which mentioned GUI toolkits operate, seems to be more suitable for your needs. Those toolkits are not programming languages, but libraries written in specific language (though sometimes with own extensions).

I discourage Qt in this case, because it has terrible `Model/View` implementation (and this is particularly what you need). For GTK there is [Gnome-DB](http://www.gnome-db.org/) project. If I were you, I would take a look at [Dabo](http://www.dabodev.com/).

c. I'm not sure what you mean by config file and if you mean some plugin system or interpreter, but I think that it will be much more straight-forward with interpretable language like Python, Ruby, PHP etc. However, since your file is huge, I'm not sure if they persist without some tweaking. Processing such files is a challenge in itself.

There is also an option to export your file to database and use some database manipulation software.

If you have statistical data then you may take a look at [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29) and GUI front-end like RKWard.

Comment: Yours was the best and closest answer. I did get lot of information from your answer. Thanks!